# Input Box Freezes After Pressing Escape Key on an Alert Message Box on Chrome/Edge on Windows

Tags: javascript, html

I am showing an `alert()` message in the `onkeyup` event of an `input` element when the user presses the enter key. If the user presses Ok button or presses Enter key to close the alert box, everything is fine. But when the user presses the Escape button to close the alert, the textbox freezes. It wouldn't be focused on, won't be typed on, as if it is disabled.

How do I fix that?

Note: the problem won't appear in jsfiddle

EDIT:

I believe the behavior is different if the code is hosted in sites like jsfiddle, even in the Run Code Snippet here in SO. Please try to replicate the problem by actually saving the code in an html file. then run it locally

UPDATE:

I'm using Windows 10. I found out problem only happens on Google Chrome/Microsoft Edge. It doesn't happen on Firefox.

I was able to replicate the problem in virtual machine in cloud. Google Chrome on Windows Server 2022. I even used its On Screen Keyboard to make sure it is not a hardware problem.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onkeyup = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      alert('Press Escape Key. The textbox will freeze.');
    };

  }
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Press Enter Here" />
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to somewhere in which this issue *is* reproducible...?

Comment: Works fine for me here on Chrome 97 (OSX)

Comment: Works fine for me also (Chrome Version 97.0.4692.99)
I think it's your keyboard that's making the issue. It'll only occur if the user's Esc button is disabled/ faulty.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments. I tried in all my browsers. same problem. I believe the behavior is different if the code is hosted in sites like jsfiddle, even in the Run Code Snippet here in SO. Please try to replicate the problem by actually saving the code in an html file. then run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried saving the code in an html file and running it locally. But the code works fine. The input box works fine for me and didn't get freeze by pressing Escape button. Even when I tried running the script in this stackoverflow site, it worked here too.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onkeyup = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      alert('Press Escape Key. The textbox will freeze.');
    };

  }
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Press Enter Here" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Vibhor Goyal. After reading your answer, I was inspired to try it on Firefox and it worked! No problems in Firefox. I updated my post